# How to prove independence is not a transitive relation?

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are independent, and $B$ and $C$ are independent.

Is $B$ independent of $A \cap C$?  Is $B$ independent of $A \cup C$? If so, prove. If not so, give a counterexample.

Could someone give some hints on how to prove them? I am quite confused about them.

Comment: The title seems to be misleadingly addressing people to answer to a different problem ("does $A$ independent on $B$ and $B$ independent on $C$ implies $A$ idependent on $C$?")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a visual counterexample:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

The probability of rain here (in Boston) is pretty close to independent of the probability of rain in north London and the rain in south London. But those two events are probably correlated.

Edit in response to comments. True enough - I answered the question in the title, not in the post. Fortunately, there are two correct answers. Here's another that may be useful.

Flip two coins. $A$ is first coin heads, $C$ is second coin heads and $B$ is that the coins agree. Then each event is independent of each of the other two and each has probability $1/2$.  $A \cap C$ say both coins are heads, so $B$ is true - hence not independent of $A \cap C$ . $A \cup C$ says there's at least one head, so two tails can't happen and the probability of $B$ is just $1/3$, so $B$ is not independent of $A \cup C$ .

In fact, in this example you can take any one of the three events and think of it as the middle one that the other two are independent of.

Comment: This answer does not address the question at all. For instance, the question asks about the independence of three events, but there are not even three here.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: rain in boston, rain in north London, rain in south London -- three events.  Two pairs of them are independent, one pair is not.

Comment: @HughThomas Ah, sorry; I had misread. That's still not what the question asks though. It's not "If A is indepedent of B and B is independent of C, is A independent of C?" which seems addressed here. That's what the title has, but the body of the post says something else. For what is asked, you'd be wanting to know whether rain in Boston is independent of it raining in either/both South/North London.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: Good point!  Though if the OP really doesn't mean to ask the question in the title, s/he should probably change the title.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with $\mathbb P(E)=\frac{|E|}6$ for $E\subset\Omega$. Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{1,4\}$, and $C=\{1,5,6\}$. Then $$\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B) = \mathbb P(B\cap C) =\mathbb P(B)\mathbb P(C) = \frac16,$$ so $A$ and $B$ are independent and $B$ and $C$ are independent. But $$\mathbb P(B\cap(A\cap C)) = \frac16\ne \frac1{18}=\mathbb P(B)\mathbb P(A\cap C) $$ and $$\mathbb P(B\cap(A\cup C))=\frac16\ne \frac5{18}=\mathbb P(B)\mathbb P(A\cup C), $$ so $B$ is not independent of $A\cap C$ or $A\cup C$.

Comment: This case is great! Thanks!

Comment: @Aky Indeed, I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 6):

I flip two coins. Let $A$ be the event that the first coin lands heads up, and let $B$ be the event the second coin lands heads up. **Let $C$ be the same event as $A$!**

$A$ and $B$ are independent, and $B$ and $C$ are independent, but $A$ and $C$ are as far from independent as it gets.

Comment: That's an interesting case. I've never thought about that A could be the same case as C. Thanks~~~

Comment: This is a good and an easy-to-remember example which I want to internalize for future reference; thank you for sharing.